# SQL "group the rows" - (confusing exam question)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I got one question for SQL query (sql server) for which I am very confused what they want to me display in the first place. This is one exam question, so I do not believe it's a mistake and unfortunately I cannot ask for clarification.

Question:

**"Write a query that has the following columns:
Transaction ID, Stock type.
Group the rows according to the portfolio."**

My current query will be:

```
select p.prfid 'Portfolio', t.trdnbr 'Transaction ID',  s.instype 'Stock Type'
from transaction t, stock s, portfolio p
where t.insaddr = s.insaddr
and t.prfnbr = p.prfnbr
```

One portfolio can have multiple transactions, but I am confused because they are not looking for number of transactions per portfolio (in which way **"group by"** will have total sense), so I am not sure in which way I should group them (except of simple sorting).
Also I was wondered if they expected me to write portfolio name in the where clause in order to group similar transactions... I don't know I am very confused.
Please help at least in which way you think they want me to present the result.

My current sample output for better view of data (it **DOES NOT** mean it should look like that))

```
  Portfolio   Transaction ID      Stock Type

    Cash       1001               Deposit    
    Cash       1002               Currency
    Crypto     1003               Stock
```

Thanks

Comment: Considering that a `group by` without an aggregation of values has a similar effect as a `select distinct` has this is still a valid question...

Comment: @Tyron78  I have updated my  current output so you can take a look how it looks like currently (it does not mean it should look like that)

Comment: @Tyron78 could you provide me with the sql query or output that you should think is the result...`distinct` as I can see produce the same output like the regular sql query without it... thanks

Comment: My guess: "Group the rows" should read "Sort the rows"

Comment: @ChrisLear thanks for your involvement... probably that would mean that I should get rid off the portfolio column in `select` and only put it within the `order by` clause

Comment: @Tyron78 so you would put `distinct` before the "Portfolio" column, right?

Comment: @AndreyDonald they ask for grouping, so I suggest you add `GROUP BY p.prfid, t.trdnbr ,  s.instype ORDER BY p.prfid, t.trdnbr ,  s.instype` - maybe there will be a follow up question such as "Now basing on your query add a SUM of..."... otherwise they would have asked something like "please display a distinct list of portfolios and ..."

Comment: @Tyron78 thank you Tyron, yeah probably that's a good idea to do it like that...

Comment: I also recommend not using single quotes (`'`) for column aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings. Though the syntax works it's the only place it does. Something like `ORDER BY 'MyColumn'` would ***not*** order the data by the column aliased with `'MyColumn'`, it would order it on the literal string `'MyColumn'`; which as it is therefore the same for every row would mean the order is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @Larnu thank you Larnu but that is not related to the basic question for which I kindly ask for help

Comment: Using 32 year old implicit join syntax is also not related to the "basic" question you asked (with respect if it's basic, shouldn't you have been able to answer it yourself with a little research? :) ) but that doesn't mean you should be doing it either. If you're answering exam questions you should be using good habits, not bad ones.

Comment: @Larnu  I wouldn't like to argue... I meant "basic" in the sense of the "main" issue for the question... I didn't mean in the context of "easy" question, like you mentioned, That wasn't my intention.. Thanks for the efforts in any case, but your answer is missing the point for "main" and the initial issue of this question.. how I will join it is not of any importance at all for the problem I am dealing with.. Thanks once again

Comment: If you are paying money for any course offering this exam, you are being cheated. Unfortunately, all anyone can do is guess; everyone but you has no context with regard to the goal of your quiz and what recent concepts (in your course) it is intended to test and reinforce. The question is poorly written and very confusing. You will need to simply guess and write something that runs without errors. There is no way to make "sense" of this question that I can see.